# My Leave Request History updates incorrectly

Tags: sap-fiori

In the history of the App "My Leave History v2" on new installed Fiori 2.0 the entries have a weird behaviour on delete.

For example if we delete the first entry with the reason "Leave" the entry disappears but the headline "Leave" stays on first position and overwrites the headline of the old second entry.

Is this behaviour known? If you need more information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to report this issue to SAP support on component PA-FIO.